# How do I write nontype output to a file in python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, elementtree, non-type

I am using ElementTree to parse some XML.
To acomplish this I wrote the following code:

```
dummy = 'TEXT: ' + str(node.text)
test.write(dummy)
test.write('\n')
```

This resulted in the following error:

UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 300-301: ordinal not in range(128)

So I tried the following:

```
dummy = 'TEXT: ' + node.text.encode('utf=8')
test.write(dummy)
test.write('\n')
```

This resulted in another error:

"AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'encode'"

How can I write the outcome of node.text properly to a file?

Comment: What's `node.text`? That's not a string.

Comment: `node.text` has returned None, you should first check if it actually returns a string.

Comment: Good points. I totally overlooked that. Thank you.